# onclickListner for AlertDialog

Tags: android

Can I set an `onclickListner` for `AlertDialog`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three types of button in AlertDialog: positive button, negative button and neutral button. You can set click listener for each of them. AlertDialog.Builder provides a easy way to create AlertDialog, and apis to let you set listeners for those three buttons which I just mentioned. These listeners must implements [`DialogInterface.OnClickListener`](http://androidappdocs.appspot.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html).

Following are three methods you can use to set listeners for dialog buttons:

- AlertDialog.Builder.setPositiveButton
- AlertDialog.Builder.setNegativeButton
- AlertDialog.Builder.setNeutralButton